# call callback function only once

Tags: reactjs, callback, use-effect, use-state

I am working on a fullstack project with ReactJS in front and it has user management.

Some pages are available only if the user is connected, so basically, I am checking it by asking my server, and I am doing it in my `NavBar.js` component (because it used in every pages).

it looks like something like this:

```
const Navigation = ({ callback }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        axios({
            method: "GET",
            withCredentials: true,
            url: process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER + "/user",
        }).then((res) => {
            if (callback) 
                callback(res.data.username);
            setUser(res.data.username);
        }).catch((e) => {
            if (callback)
                callback(null);
        });
    }, [callback])

    return (
        <div>Some navbar stuff</div>
    )
}

export default Navigation;
```

and inside my other pages, I use my Navigation component like this :

```
const PublishContent = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    const handleUserName = e => {
        setUser(e);
        setLoading(false);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Navigation callback={handleUserName} />
            {
                !loading && <div>{user ? <div>CONNECTED</div> : <div> NOT CONNECTED</div>} </div>
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default PublishContent;
```

My problem is that my `handleUserName` is called three times, I don't understand why, even if `callback` is the the dependency list of my `UseEffect`, it should be constant...

Also, since `useState` is async, even if the user is logged, the first time my `user` is undefined.

Do you know how I can solve this problem ? Also, can you tell me if the way I am doing (checking if user is authenticated, sounds weird to you ? Thank you.

Comment: PSA, you can use [@welldone-software/why-did-you-render](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@welldone-software/why-did-you-render) on npm to track why certain components have rendered. Saves a lot of hassle. :)

Comment: The problem might come from the creation of a new function for `handleUserName` at each render. You can fix it using useCallback. In the Navigation component, I don't understand how this instruction `setUser(res.data.username);` could work without error. Why don't you simply load the user in the `PublishContent` component rather than in the `Navigation` component

Comment: @OlivierBoissé what do you mean by `setUser(res.data.username);` couldn't work ? `res.data.username` corresponds to a string, so I don't get the problem

Comment: @OlivierBoissé I don't load the user in the component, because I don't want to copy paste the code in every pages, so because `Navigation` is included on every pages, I'd rather check if my user is connected on that component.

Comment: where does the `setUser` method come from ? I don't see it in the Navigation component

Comment: @OlivierBoissé I don't call `setUser`, but `callback` which corresponds to `handleUserName` (that contains `setUser`)

Comment: look at your post => `then((res) => {
            if (callback) 
                callback(res.data.username);
            setUser(res.data.username);
        })`

Comment: @OlivierBoissé Oh sorry, `setUser` is another method declared inside `Navigation` component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time `handleUserName` is called it's going to call setUser and setLoading which both will initiated a re-render. When the PublishContent component re-renders (twice in this instance) it will create a new function and assign it to handleUserName which then gets passed into your Navigation component and into your useEffect, causing your useEffect to re-run since the dependency has changed (new function as a result of re-rendering). To solve your problem you just need to wrap handleUserName in a useCallback like so

```js
const handleUserName = useCallback((e) => {
  setUser(e)
  setLoading(false)
}, [])
```

You also shouldn't be calling setUser in Navigation. If you need to access it you can pass it down as a prop

```js
const PublishContent = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    const handleUserName = useCallback(e => {
        setUser(e);
        setLoading(false);
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <Navigation callback={handleUserName} user={user} />
            {
                !loading && <div>{user ? <div>CONNECTED</div> : <div> NOT CONNECTED</div>} </div>
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default PublishContent;
```